# Группировка данных в pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, анализ

Имеется данные формата chknum, person_id, day, month, good_id.
Проблема заключается в том, что каждая строчка имеет п одному значению в поле good_id. То есть один чек имеет несколько полей, которые дублируют все значения, кроме good_id. Требуется объединить данные как раз по признаку chknum, при этом good_id теперь должно быть в виде массива.

Вот моя попытка:
train.groupby('chknum')[good_id].unique()
выводится во-первых, только 2 столбца, но это понятно почему
Во-вторых, chknum только 0, 1, 10, 100 и 1000
Вот входные данные

[image: Вот входные данные]

А вот выход для этих данных

[image: А вот пример выходных для этих данных]

---

[Вот первые 20 элементов данных](https://github.com/Damir214/pandas_problem/blob/master/data.csv)

Comment: Приведите небольшой пример входных данных (в виде текста или CSV) и то что вы хотите получить на выходе.

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [27]: df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Damir214/pandas_problem/master/data.csv')

In [28]: res = df.groupby(df.columns.drop('good_id').tolist(), as_index=False).agg(list)

In [29]: res
Out[29]:
  chknum  person_id  month  day                    good_id
0    id0          1      1   17           [12, 13, 8, 124]
1    id1        626      1   17     [181, 46, 216, 124, 8]
2    id2       1438      1   17     [121, 43, 124, 8, 105]
3    id3        190      1   17  [184, 157, 46, 139, 3, 3]
```

---

Пояснение:

```
In [64]: df.columns.drop('good_id').tolist()
Out[64]: ['chknum', 'person_id', 'month', 'day']
```

возвращает список столбцов по которым мы хотим осуществить группировку.

Следующая конструкция агрегирует сгрупированные данные и применяет `list(...)` в качестве функции агрегации к значениям в столбце `good_id`:

```
In [65]: df.groupby(df.columns.drop('good_id').tolist(), as_index=False)['good_id'].agg(list)
Out[65]:
  chknum  person_id  month  day                    good_id
0    id0          1      1   17           [12, 13, 8, 124]
1    id1        626      1   17     [181, 46, 216, 124, 8]
2    id2       1438      1   17     [121, 43, 124, 8, 105]
3    id3        190      1   17  [184, 157, 46, 139, 3, 3]
```

т.к. в сгрупированном DataFrame *единственный* столбец не учавствуюший в группировке - `['good_id']` можно убрать:

```
In [66]: df.groupby(df.columns.drop('good_id').tolist(), as_index=False).agg(list)
Out[66]:
  chknum  person_id  month  day                    good_id
0    id0          1      1   17           [12, 13, 8, 124]
1    id1        626      1   17     [181, 46, 216, 124, 8]
2    id2       1438      1   17     [121, 43, 124, 8, 105]
3    id3        190      1   17  [184, 157, 46, 139, 3, 3]
```

в этом случае агрегирование применяется ко всем столбцам не учавствуюшим в группировке.

Comment: Спасибо большое, а можно попросить объяснить, что происходит здесь
Группируется по всем столбцам, но почему идет преобразование в list
agg - применяется к оставшимся столбцам как я понимаю. Типо как в count, sum и т.п.

Comment: @ДамирАбдуллин, добавил пояснения в ответ...